# OnTextChanged event is not firing

Tags: asp.net, events, textbox

I have a TextBox inside my .Aspx page:

```
<ajax:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtCity_TextChanged"
            Width="90%" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</ajax:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void txtCity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "you have typed:" + txtCity.Text;
}
```

And for `lblMessage` [on the same .Aspx page]:

```
<ajax:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</ajax:UpdatePanel>
```

But when I am typing in the TextBox. `lblMessage` is not updating.

How to rectify this?

Comment: When you say "when I am typing in the textbox" you mean, when you type in the textbox and submit it right?

Comment: Even assuming the server-side method will actually execute (which given your current code it won't, unless you submit as Drackir says), you're forgetting to call `.Update()` on UpdatePanel1 after the Label text update.

Comment: @Drackir  What I want is to show the text I am typing in the textbox without postback.

Comment: See my answer. You're looking for a JavaScript solution, not an ASP one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking that the `OnTextChange` event is fired while you are typing in the text box. This is not true. `OnTextChange` is a server-side event and only fires when the page (or panel) is posted back. Typing into a text box on a page does not post the page back and so this event will only fire once you submit the form.

What you would actually want to do in this case, is to use some JavaScript with the `onkeypress` JavaScript event to update the label text as things are typed into the TextBox. JavaScript is run on the client and doesn't require you to post back the page in order for it to run.

Comment: That's so sad. I was trying the same thing ):